# How to compare two CSV files cell by cell and calculate the percentage of similarities?

Tags: python, loops, csv, compare

I'm kind of confused by now. I have 2 files:

- **File A:**

  > 10050 Jane 
  >   10669 Doe 
  >   12931 dumb
- **File B:**

  > Do 
  >   dumb 
  >   Jan

What I want to do is match the names on the first file with names on the second file based on the percentage of similarities of each component.

create a new column,

I'm thinking about using loop,

1 to 2 1 to 3 and 1 to 4, so on and so forth, and cell on the second file with the highest percentage will be on the same line with the first component

**How do I do that?** I have 2 files with thousands of names that need to be compared.

Comment: the standard library difflib can be useful

Comment: Is it a line by line comparison? If yes, the problem can be: how to compare string. You can consider using Levenshtein distance.

Comment: https://pymotw.com/3/difflib/ https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html

Comment: Please edit the question to show your expected output for your example.